# iOS uploading image and ID to http post

Tags: asp.net, ios, nsurlrequest

I want to upload picture to aspx web page in the http post, the web page has two keys: image and id, i want to pass image to http post and user id. I saw many codes over stackoverflow, but i don't know how to use keys to pass the data.
sorry for my bad English,
thanks

Comment: I mean that i want pass the image and id to the body using keys defined in the aspx app code

Comment: What do you mean by "keys," and what do you mean "pass the image and id to the body?"  Please post some code that you have tried to use.

Comment: I mean that i have to upload image and it's id, so the body have two attributes (keys) and i want to assign the image data to key called image that's defined by the asp developer and the id to key called id that's also defined by the asp developer, hoper you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options:

1. Create a structure, possibly JSON, that has the ID and the image data and set that as the body.
2. Send the ID in the header and the image data in the body.
3. Send the ID in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use multipart/form-data.
The most simple solution is to use AFNetworking: [AFNetworking example how to post multipart request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/#post-multi-part-request)